# How to set a persistent global variable by scripted pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I need to pass a variable from a pipeline to another one without triggering the build of the second one. 
Basically, the first pipeline should set the value of this variable and terminate. When I run the second pipeline, it should be able to get this value.
So far, I used a properties' file but I'd like to know if there is a way to avoid it. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the [EnvInject plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) is what you need.

As alternative solution:
You could also write to a file from the first job and source that file from your second job if it is started. The location must be persistent, do not use the workspace dir.